# javascript issue with fixed position side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website with a sidebar that, once the user scrolls past a certain point it becomes fixed on the site. This code works fine.

The issue that I am coming into is that the sidebar is overlapping the footer when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. I wrote code to detect when the bottom of the sidebar hits the same position as it's containing element - when that happens I am taking the position of the bottom of the containing element and subtract the height of the sidebar element and using that number to give the sidebar it's new "top" (while also changing the position to "absolute").

This is where I am running into the issue - once the sidebar is overtop of the footer as the user scrolls the code that is getting called alternates between the normal "fixed" position code and the "absolute" positioned code giving it this flickering effect.

For the life of me I can't figure out why the "fixed" code keeps getting called.

Here is the code:

```
    ( function( $ ) {

        var sidebar_pos = $('#secondary')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var pos_top = sidebar_pos.top + window.scrollY; //need this to get the pos of TOP in the browser - NOT the viewport
        var main_pos = $('.main-content')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var main_bottom = main_pos.bottom  + window.scrollY;
        var stop_pos;
        var i = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var produce_pos = $('.produce')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var pos_bottom = produce_pos.bottom  + window.scrollY;
            //console.log("scroll "+scroll);
            //console.log("top " + pos_top);
            console.log(main_bottom);
            console.log('bottom ' + pos_bottom);
               if( scroll >= pos_top){
                if ( pos_bottom >= main_bottom ){
                    //if the sidebar would end up overlapping the footer
                    if(i == 0){
                        //only need to set this once, not on every scroll
                        stop_pos = main_bottom  - $('#secondary').height() ;
                    } 
                    $('#secondary').removeClass('hover').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        margin:0,
                        left: sidebar_pos.left,
                        top: stop_pos
                    });
                    i++;
                } else {
                    $('#secondary').addClass('hover').css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        left: sidebar_pos.left,
                        marginTop: '1.5em',
                        top: 20
                    });
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        $('*[data-widget="comet"]').addClass('active');
                    }, 5000);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        $('*[data-widget="produce"]').addClass('active');
                    }, 7000);
                }
            } else if( scroll < pos_top && $('#secondary').hasClass('hover') ){  //if user scrolls up past original pos of sidebar, remove effects
                $('#secondary').removeClass('hover').css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: 'auto',
                    top: 'auto'
                });
                i = 0;
            }
        });
}( jQuery ) );
```

I also have a codepen of the script in action.
https://codepen.io/antlaur00/pen/ExyrgYR

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well its pretty simple, just add Z-index property to your footer CSS, that way it will always overlap your sidebar .
You can refer to this article regarding the z-index property
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I don't want it to slide underneath, I want it to top at the bottom of the containing element.